# EGOcache cocoa pod there are no examples so how does it work

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm working on a ipad app in xcode and wan't to cache some data.
Everywhere and also on stack overflow pleople say use EGOcache.
The site shows that lots of people use this https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache
But everybody seems to get how it works and i don't.

But they leave no examples and the aren't any to be found.

So if you have experience please show me 3 things.

Save NSData with an key,
Get NSData with an key,
Clear cache

For save with timer i think this is correct:

```
[self.cache setData:data0 forKey:@"MessagesCache" withTimeoutInterval:timer];
```

For clear cache this:

```
[self.cache clearCache];
```

But getting i have no idea, so i can't test it.

self.cache is an instantiation of the EGOcache implementation file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) EGOCache *cache;
```

Hope for help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a property for EGOCache.  Instead of what you had use this:

```
[[EGOCache globalCache] setData:data0 forKey:@"MessagesCache"];
```

To clear it do this:

```
if ([[EGOCache globalCache] hasCacheForKey:@"MessagesCache"]) {
    [[EGOCache globalCache] removeCacheForKey:@"MessagesCache"];
}
```

You don't really have to see if the cache exists before removing it, but I prefer the safe approach in case the underlying removeCacheForKey implementation changes.

I really wouldn't worry about the withTimeoutInterval param either.  I've never used it and never had a need to.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And the timeout is a something that is necessary for me. The cache had to be removed after some time too force the user to update the data.

Answer (score 3):

In the Objective-C world in a case like this when there isn't as much documentation as I think there *should* be, I go straight to the header file. Then in your case I would look for a method named something like `setData` (I assumed this name even before I had read the header to answer this) which is [here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache/blob/master/EGOCache.h#L49). Then you would use `dataForKey:` from [here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache/blob/master/EGOCache.h#L48) and finally `clearCache` from [here](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache/blob/master/EGOCache.h#L43) so in short, yep your assumptions looked correct.

Comment: Thanks for your share and please accept my admire. It reminds me of an old saying, "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day". That's what I desperately need for now. Thanks again.